# To prove that the given function is smooth

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $r>0$, I have to prove that the function $g_r\colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as $g_r(x) = f(r^2 - |x|^2)$ for $|x| < r$ and $g_r(x) = 0$ for $|x| \geq r$ is smooth. Where the function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $f(t) = e^{-1/t^2}$ for $t \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$.

Now, I was able to show that $f \in C^{\infty}$. So it stands to reason that it can be shown that $g_r(x) \in C^{\infty}$ by using similar arguments used for proving the smoothness of $f$. But I think I may be missing something. Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: The chain rule implies that $g_r$ is differentiable whenever $x\neq 0,$ in which case case you can consider the one-sided limits in the definition of derivative.

Comment: Do you mean whenever $r^2-|x|^2 \neq 0$?

Comment: No. you have already shown that $f$ is diff there.

Comment: So, I just need to show that $g_r$ is differentiable whenever $x=0$?